# JPA Transaction error when calling super's method

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, spring-transactions

I have a method like :

```
package com.abc.pkg.service.db.impl;



public class OperationServiceImpl extends BaseService implements OperationService {



    @Transactional
        @Override
        public String update(Operation operation,User user) {

        BigDecimal count=(BigDecimal)em.createNativeQuery("select count(*) from RBMCORE.T_RBM_OPSCREENS_OPERATIONS where s_name= ? and id!= ?").setParameter(1, operation.getName()).setParameter(2, operation.getId()).getSingleResult();

        if(count.intValue()>0)
            return "This operation name is used by another operation. Please change it";

        super.removeOpAppRelation(operation.getId(), -1);

        Operation oldOperation=operationRepository.save(operation);
        List<Operation> operations=new ArrayList<Operation>();
        operations.add(operation);
}
}
```

and the super.insertOpAppRelation method content is:

```
package com.abc.pkg.service.db.impl;
public abstract class BaseService {


@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;

@Transactional
    protected  void removeOpAppRelation(int opId,int appId){
        String sql="delete table a where 1=1";
        if(opId>0)
            sql+=" and op_id="+opId;

        if(appId>0)
            sql+=" and app_id="+appId;

        em.createNativeQuery(sql).executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

And removeOpAppRelation method is triggered, this exception is thrown:

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an
>   update/delete query

and in my appcontext.xml I have these:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.pck"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="rbmDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ttech.rbm.model"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

As transaction manager, I am using:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager

Any ideas? Is it related with the inheritance?

Comment: Are both the class and super class located under `com.abc.pck` package?

Comment: They are under exactly the same package. but the full package name is not com.abc.pck . It is com.abc.pck.service.db.impl. I have made it as prefix package in order to make it scan all the sub packages

Comment: Hmm.. there isn't enough info to further debug your problem. I suggest you set org.hibernate.transaction logger to DEBUG (or org.hibernate.engine.transaction on hibernate 4.2 or newer), and from your log you will see transaction begin/commit

Comment: Actually I am using hibernate with JPA. The other difference in here is, I am calling this method from somewhere else(@controller annotated class) and I do now come across this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. the entity manager that I have passed into the transaction manager is not AOP safe. because of it, it does not start a transaction while executing a query with it. I have opened and managed my own transaction and problem solved. Thanks for replies

Answer (score 0):

Your code is to much simplified.

The "em" used is not declared in any of your classes.

I would expect an

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
```

in one of your classes.

If it's in both classes it would explain your error, because in this case two different entity managers will be injected which will not share the same transaction.

To avoid this you should use an abstract method "getEm()" in your superclass and override it in your child class, providing the em injected there.

In addition the @Transactional on the superclass will have no effect when called from the child class, because the super-method it's called directly from the child and not through a spring-aop-proxy - spring has no chance to intercept.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I have edited the question. Now, as u can see that there is an an entity manager and transaction manager handles the transactions of entity manager. And I think , because of entityManager object is a protected one, it is singleton on child and parent class(because they all share one entityManager object). So after my update on question, any ideas?

Comment: If there would be no transaction at all I would expect the exception in OperationServiceImpl.update(..) because it's already neede there. You can try to move @Transactional to the interface method OperationService.update(..).

Comment: And OperationServiceImpl.update(..) must not be called from inside OperationServiceImpl.